# How can I provide a default protocol confromance of subsript for only class types?

Tags: swift, protocols

**Marking CacheManager with 'class' solved my problem.**

**Here's the case: a simple cacher**, the mutating get is not what I want, so how should do for the reference types or just class type?

```
protocol Cacher {
    associatedtype K
    associatedtype V
    subscript (key: K) -> V? {get set}
}

protocol MemoryCacher: Cacher {}

protocol FileCacher: Cacher {}
```

**updated**. add PrimayCacher | SecondaryCacher associatedtypes

```
protocol CacheManager {
    associatedtype Key
    associatedtype Value
    associatedtype PrimaryCacher: MemoryCacher where PrimaryCacher.K == Key, PrimaryCacher.V == Value
    associatedtype SecondaryCacher: FileCacher where SecondaryCacher.K == Key, SecondaryCacher.V == Value
    var primaryCacher: PrimaryCacher  { get set }
    var secondaryCacher: SecondaryCacher{ get set }
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? { get set }
}

//try to provide a default subscript conformance, but actually not for the `mutating` get
extension CacheManager  {
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        mutating get {
            guard let result = primaryCacher[key] else {
                if let value = secondaryCacher?[key] {
                    primaryCacher[key] = value // the mutating is required for this
                    return value
                }
                return nil
            }
            return result
        }
        set {
            primaryCacher[key] = newValue
            secondaryCacher?[key] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `mutating` at all. Just delete it, no errors.

Comment: @Sweeper But I do get an error: "Cannot assign through subscript: 'self' is immutable"

Comment: [no errors](https://repl.it/repls/RuralProperPlan).

Comment: @Sweeper code updated. What about this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a type restriction to `AnyObject`, which all classes conform to.

```
extension CacherManager where Self: AnyObject {
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get {
            guard let result = primaryCacher[key] else {
                if let value = secondaryCacher?[key] {
                    primaryCacher[key] = value // the mutating is required for this
                    return value
                }
                return nil
            }
            return result
        }
        set {
            primaryCacher[key] = newValue
            secondaryCacher?[key] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I also had to slightly modify your `CacheManager` declaration for the code to compile and add the required protocol methods to `MemoryCacher` and `FileCacher` that you omitted from the question.

```
protocol Cacher {
    associatedtype K
    associatedtype V
    subscript (key: K) -> V? {get set}
}

class MemoryCacher<K, V>: Cacher {
    private var value: V?

    subscript(key: K) -> V? {
        get {
            return value
        }
        set {
            value = newValue
        }
    }
}

class FileCacher<K, V>: Cacher {
    private var value: V?

    subscript(key: K) -> V? {
        get {
            return value
        }
        set {
            value = newValue
        }
    }
}

protocol CacheManager {
    associatedtype Key
    associatedtype Value
    var primaryCacher: MemoryCacher<Key,Value> { get set }
    var secondaryCacher: FileCacher<Key,Value>? { get set }
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? { get set }
}
```

Comment: the compiler still says: "Cannot assign through subscript: 'self' is immutable"

Comment: @K.F what compiler version are you using? That piece of code compiles just fine for me using Swift 5. All (pure) Swift classes conform to `AnyObject`. `AnyObject` is a Swift protocol that all classes conform to, it is completely unrelated to `NSObject`. Also, which line is giving you the error?

Comment: Yah, it's not related to NSObject. I'm also in Swift 5. You sure that's fine for you?

Comment: @K.F in that case you most probably have issues with your protocol declaration. I had to modify `CacheManager` to include `var primaryCacher: MemoryCacher<Key,Value> { get set }
    var secondaryCacher: FileCacher<Key,Value>? { get set }` for it to compile and also provide the `subscript` implementation for `MemoryCacher` and `FileCacher` for the code to compile. I've updated my answer with the full working example

Comment: When I run that code solely in Playground, as @Sweeper says, the 'mutating' is not really required at all, even without AnyObject. Thx.

Comment: @Dávid.Pásztor updated. That's my real case. It do has this problem.